# Contextual MySQL result searching 2 columns

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I have this Table

```
ID    |   NAME            |   ACCOUNT

1     |   Visa            |   1000
2     |   MC              |   3333
3     |   Comptant        |   5000
4     |   Something       |   6000
5     |   Compte Client   |   2000
```

i need a search on colums ID and ACCOUNT

Result:
If ID = 3 and ACCOUNT != 2000

```
ID    |   NAME            |   ACCOUNT
3     |   Comptant        |   5000
```

BUT

If ID = 5 and ACCOUNT != 2000 then return only ACCOUNT != 2000 limit 1

```
ID    |   NAME            |   ACCOUNT
1     |   Visa            |   1000
```

I tried **UNION** but it fetch the same data on any search query.

Comment: I think you need to search only by account (if I understand it), not ID, although I didn't quite understand what you are trying to get here.

Comment: I cant, the structure is already in place with on a side the id and on the other side the account

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to return one row that comes closest to meeting your requirements.  If so, use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select t.*
from thistable t
order by (account <> 2000) desc,
         (id = 3) desc;
limit 1;
```

Comment: I didnt know i can use order to filter, does it also work on sqlite ?  Btw : thanks a lot !

Comment: @EtiennePilon . . . The question is tagged "mysql", not "sqlite".  In SQLite, you might need to wrap the conditions in a `case` statement to turn them into 0/1 values.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, yes i know it's a MySQL question, this is why i ask if it also works on SQLite... thanks for the cue i will try (btw it works very fine :-) thanks again !)

Comment: It just tried it on SQLite, it's also working :-) that is pretty cool :-) thanks again ! @Gordon !